# Parse JSON without object name in Java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse this JSON which is coming as the response to a REST API call. Can you please help me parsing it as key value pairs?

The object names are not present. There is nesting as well. There seems to be no new line between records.

The aim is to extract this data and load it into a database.

```
    [
    {
        "cc_emails":["feedback@xyz.com"],
        "fwd_emails":[],
        "reply_cc_emails":["feedback@xyz.com"],
        "fr_escalated":false,
        "spam":false,
        "email_config_id":6000038087,
        "group_id":6000110481,
        "priority":1,
        "requester_id":6010410791,
        "responder_id":6002817857,
        "source":1,
        "company_id":null,
        "status":2,
        "subject":"fare",
        "to_emails":["feedback@xyz.com"],
        "product_id":null,
        "id":45043,
        "type":null,
        "due_by":"2016-03-12T08:58:02Z",
        "fr_due_by":"2016-03-08T08:58:02Z",
        "is_escalated":false,
        "description":"Dear xyze Team,\r\n\r\nWhy r u increased fair again and againasas0mail.gmail.com</a>.<br>\n",
        "custom_fields":
        {
            "category":null,
            "issue":null,
            "route_id":null,
            "phone_number":null,
            "department":null,
            "booking_id":null
        },
        "created_at":"2016-03-07T08:58:02Z",
        "updated_at":"2016-03-07T08:58:03Z",

// ...... repeat

}
]
```

Comment: have u tried anything yet?#

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
Enter your json there
Change source type to JSON
set the correct class name and package.
The resulting pojo can be directly mapped from the json

If you are using resttemplate to hit the api then you can use getForObject to automatically set the pojo from the output.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-

Answer (score 0):

Using gson you can do this quite simply.

Do a class to match the fields in the json something like:

```
    public class Example {
        private List<String> cc_emails;
        private List<String> fwd_emails;
        private List<String> reply_cc_emails;
        private Boolean fr_escalated;
        private Boolean spam;
        private Integer email_config_id;
        ...
        private CustomFields custom_fields;
        private String created_at;
        private String updated_at;

    }
```

Then you need to do another to map the custom fields

```
public class CustomFields {

   private String category;
   ...


}
```

And using json you can parse it like this:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Collection<Example>>(){}.getType();
new Gson().fromJson(json,type);
```

You have to exaplain to Gson it's a list, if it was a single object it would be this:

```
new Gson().fromJson(json,Example.class);
```

This is the aproach I usually take, also in the dates java.sql.Timestamp class might also parse it, you would need to try it though.

Comment: Thanks for making it so easy.! :-)
I defined first level structure in one class, then used Map instead of class for customFields.
To fetch first level of key-value :
for(int i =0; i<gson.size(); i++)
System.out.println(gson.get(i).getTo_emails());

I am stuck at second level in iterating the Map:
for(int i=0;i<gson.get(i).getCustom_fields().size(); i++ )
??????What here?????

Comment: You should also check for nulls, since you are parsing json from another source. But since you are iterating through the whole map, try this:

`for (String s : gson.get(i).getCustom_fields().values() ) {
            ...
        }`

if interested in both key and value you have to use this:

`for (Map.Entry<String, String> s : strings.entrySet() ) {
            ...
        }`

Comment: Drunk how it's working, I tried same but no luck your Example is inside [ Example ], how you resolved [ ].